# Correct way to use a local Django project in a new computer (VS Code)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code

I created my first local Python/Django project a few months ago using Visual Studio Code. It worked perfectly.

Now I'm trying to use it on a new computer. I've tried just saving the VS workspace and then loading it on the new computer, but it gives me the following error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gad'
```

I think it's coming from the line `os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'gad.settings')` in manage.py

I don't know if I should create a Django project from scratch and then copy my "old" files into that project, if I just have to create the "gad.settings" file or what.

I don't have the old computer, but I think I have all the files from my old Django project (but there is no gad.settings file in it, so maybe I had to copy more files outside that folder).

Thanks!

Comment: What does "loading it on the new computer" mean here? You definitely don't need to create a new project from scratch – if that were the case, how would software development in teams work at all? – but you do need to recreate the environment (e.g. virtualenv) in which you worked on the old machine.

Comment: "Loading on the new computer" means running the project code on VS Code, to check if it still works on the new computer (it's 100% local, it runs only on my computer). So I can create a virtualenv from scratch following any guide or do I have to remember every step and setting that I used when I created the environment on the old computer? If it's the latter, I'm f*****, because I don't remember them at all.

Comment: You can create a virtualenv using any guide.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new virtual environment on the new machine. But it will lack other modules that have been installed in the old environment. That is why `ModuleNotFoundError` appear on your new machine.

You can use **requirements.txt** to install the same module for your new environment as the old environment.

- Activate the environment you use on the old machine, and then use the following commands in the terminal, you will get a **requirements.txt** file in the current workspace directory

  ```
  pip freeze > requirements.txt
  ```
- Copy the **requirements.txt** file to the new machine and place it in the project root directory (the root directory of the VSCODE workspace)
- After the new machine activates the virtual environment, use the following command to install the module in the terminal

  ```
  pip install -r requirements.txt
  ```

*See: [Python environment in VSCODE](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments).*

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to the old machine anymore. I saved the VScode workspace and also all the files from the project, but I can't find any gad.settings or settings.py files. That might be the problem? Maybe I'm missing some installation/migration steps?

Comment: It's just a matter of environment, install the required modules for your new environment. Use the `pip` command.